# pro tools m-powered 8 package contents

Tags: pro-tools, m-powered-8, mbox-2, in-the-box

Hi everyone I know it's been a while but the good news is I have finally moved over to pro tools!

I bought the pro tools m-powered 8 I've had the box the whole day so I opened it up and expected to find an m-box there seems to be only the manual a dongle/ikey and a booklet of dvds, I went through the manual and I'm sure there is supposed to be a fire wire connection thing (the m-box) I really don't want to install it until i know whats going on, this is my first pro tools product so excuse the ignorance (I will be running it off my macbook pro icore 7 15 inch).

Any info regarding this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why the down vote? Although not a sound design question or comment, plenty of users have posted technical questions to this forum in the past. Lighten up, people!

Comment: someone must be hating on me jay :/ thanks for the back up :D

Answer (score 1):

M-Powered ProTools does not come with a hardware interface. You're going to have to buy a M-Audio interface separately. The USB MobilePre is probably your cheapest option. The Mbox works with only with ProTools LE and won't be compatible with your ProTools M-Powered.

Comment: @paul
are you serious?! OMFG! 
can it not work without the interface?
thanks btw what do you do?

Comment: does pro tools only need the mbox to record i.e. can i stilledit sound with pro tools with out an m box?

Comment: @JM you will need what Paul says, PT will not work without it, everything you do with the software relies on the box.

Comment: @JM If you're using PT8, you need an interface to use the software, whether you want to record or not. PT9 just came out which doesn't require an interface - you could just use your computer line out to speakers. You can crossgrade from PT8 to PT9 for $349 I think and since you already have your iLok from PT8, you won't need to buy a new one.

Comment: @everyone omg so in other words i wasted my money? 

@paul (just to clarify) the usb mobilepre will work correct? please say it will cos i dont have the funds to throw away on this investment thank you all for all the info.

